# SQL pattern : compute a sum each query or save and maintain the computed sum data?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For a SQL database (PostgreSQL in my case) like:

```
A ( 1 to many ) B
B ( 1 to many ) C
```

In C and B there is a column size.

Sometimes I would like to now the global size of A (so the sum of all B/C related to A).

So it seems to be 2 ways to get the global size of A:

1. Get all B related to A + get all C related to all of these B. Then, sum the sizes. It seems to be a huge process for a simple size info.
2. Add a size column in A. And each time B or C is added/deleted/updated, update the A size column. This seems betters but need more maintenance and less flexible.

Is there any other way to do it? May be in native SQL query? Or is the 2nd option the better as it seems to be?

Example:

```
TABLE CONTAINER (id)
TABLE BOX (id, containerId)
TABLE ELEM (id, nullable boxId, nullable containerId, size)
```

Now, let's illustrate with data:

```
CONTAINER (1)
BOX (1, 1)
ELEM (1, 1, null, 30)
ELEM (1, 1, null, 100)
ELEM (1, null, 1, 15)
```

So the size of container with id = 1 will be: 145

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output to your question.

Comment: Unless you have specific constraints about your domain or queries. option 1 is the way to go. If not, you should elaborate about your problem and constraints.